# Concatenating HList Types in Case Class Definition

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have three HLists `A`, `B` and `R`. Within a case class definition I want to enforce a relationship between those three HLists.

The code looks like this:

```
trait Base[A <: HList]    
case class Concat[A <: HList, B <: HList, R <: HList](a: A, b: B) extends Base[R]
```

Is it possible to enforce that `R` is a concatenation of the HLists `A` and `B`? Or is there a way that I do not need the type `R` but still enforce that the type parameter of `Base` is a concatenation of `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Prepend`:

```
case class Concat[A <: HList, B <: HList, R <: HList](a: A, b: B)(implicit p: Prepend.Aux[A, B, R]) extends Base[R]
```

And a useful companion method for constructing without specifying `R`

```
def concat[A <: HList, B <: HList](a: A, b: B)(implicit p: Prepend[A, B]): Concat[A, B, p.Out] = Concat(a, b)(p)
```